# Updating Variable in Mysql table

Tags: mysql

Currently, I am trying to update a variable that shows whether a message has been read or not. I am attempting to do this my querying this command:

```
 $read=1;
 $sql2 ="INSERT INTO table (state) VALUES (1)  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = 1";
  mysql_query($sql2);
```

However, it does nothing at all.

Comment: why not `UPDATE tableName SET state = 1 WHERE id = 1`?

Comment: Good question! I never knew about that. After quick implementation I go it to work, thanks!